# Discord.py json files keep resetting after restarting bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So basically I made a bot that can change its prefix through a command, and it will only set that custom prefix to the server you are in. But when I rerun the program, it resets the prefixes back to default. For example if I set the prefix to ! from -, if I rerun the bot, it will set it back to !. Here's my code:

```
custom_prefixes = {}
with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
  json.load(f)
default_prefixes = ['-']

async def determine_prefix(bot, message):
guild = message.guild
#Only allow custom prefixs in guild
if guild:
    return custom_prefixes.get(guild.id, default_prefixes)
else:
    return default_prefixes

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = determine_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot loaded successfully")

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def setprefix(ctx, *, prefixes=""):
custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id] = prefixes.split() or default_prefixes
with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(custom_prefixes, f)
await ctx.send("Prefixes set!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you coded it, `custom_prefixes` will always be an empty dictionary.
You wrote `json.load(f)` to read your json file but you're not assigning any variable to this file content:

```py
with open('prefixes.json') as f:
    custom_prefixes = json.load(f)
```

In `json` files, keys must be strings and can't be integers. In your code, you're getting `guild.id` which is an integer, so `custom_prefixes.get(guild.id, default_prefixes)` will always return `default_prefixes`:

```py
def determine_prefix(bot, message):
    guild = message.guild
    if guild:
        return custom_prefixes.get(str(guild.id), default_prefixes)

    # The else statement is unnecessary
    return default_prefixes
```

Comment: It now works when you rerun the bot, but doesn't work after you set the prefix :/

Comment: `custom_prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefixes.split() or default_prefixes`